# Vue/Jest "Cannot read property 'components' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

PROBLEM FOUND, READ BELOW

Currently, after days and days of configurations, I'm getting close to the end of config. Hopefully.

The issues that are prevalent are "Cannot read property 'components' of undefined" and [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

Even the most basic of basic tests, as shown below, are tossing out Vue errors.

```
//import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
mount = require('@vue/test-utils').mount;
var pma = require('../components/profile-licenses').default;

let nacho;

beforeEach(() => {
    nacho = mount(pma)
});

afterEach(() => {
    nacho.destroy()
});

describe('ccp', () => {
    test('is a Vue instance', () => {
        expect(nacho.isVueInstance).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

The above solution is used to solve a [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. However it's not ideal. It brings in more errors and acts like it can't see vue-test-utils at all.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'components' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isVueInstance' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined
```

Here is my setup.

package.json

```
{
"scripts": {
        "dev": "cross-env NUXT_PORT=8080 nuxt-ts",
        "build": "nuxt-ts build",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.7",
        "@nuxt/typescript-runtime": "^0.3.6",
        "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.9.2",
        "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-beta.19",
        "@vue/cli": "^3.11.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
        "mem": "^6.0.1",
        "nuxt": "^2.11.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",
        "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^0.5.5",
        "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
        "@vue/server-test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.31",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.30",
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "jest": "^25.1.0",
        "nuxt-start": "^2.11.0",
        "ts-jest": "^24.3.0",
        "vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
        "vue-loader": "^15.8.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/preset-react",
            "@babel/preset-typescript"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
        ]
    },
    "jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "js",
            "json",
            "vue"
        ],
        "transform": {
            "^.*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest",
            "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
            "^.+\\.ts$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "/node_modules/(?!(@babel/preset-typescript)/)"
        ],
"moduleNameMapper": {
            "@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
            "vue$": "vue/dist/vue",
            "^vue$": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
},
        "moduleDirectories": [
            ".",
            "node_modules",
            "client"
        ]
   }
```

webpack.config

```
var path = require('path').default;
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('node_modules/vue-loader/lib/plugin').default;
module.exports = {
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {exclude: ['node_modules'], loader: 'babel', test: /\.jsx?$/},
        {loader: 'style-loader!css-loader', test: /\.css$/},
        {loader: 'url-loader', test: /\.gif$/},
        {loader: 'file-loader', test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)$/},
        {loader: 'vue-loader', test: /\.vue$/},
        {options: {
            loaders: {
            },
            esModule: false
          }}
      ],
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                cacheDirectory: true,
                presets: ['es2015']
              }
            }
          ]
        }, {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'vue-loader'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          include: [
            path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/')
          ],
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: ['transform-es2015-block-scoping'],
                cacheDirectory: true
              }
            }
          ],
        },
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
         },
      extensions: [ '.vue', '.ts', '.js'],
      modules: [
        'node_modules'
      ],
      plugins: [ new VueLoaderPlugin() ]
    }
  };
```

I wouldn't be surprised if this was a config error. I've been in endless config for days now. All the solutions I've tried so far aren't working. I'm trying to set up testing on a project that has lots of components and isn't a SPA.

***EDIT:***
This, actually, is not a config issue! At least not in this current case.

I tried setting up testing on a couple other files, and found several that were able to run without encountering any Vue errors at all.

The mounting issue that I was having was due to there being a weird parent-child dynamic that I hadn't realized was there. We had the Vue file as its own component and there was a popup component as well.

Looking closer at the vue template, we were slotting the popup component with data from the original component. Thus the "Failed to mount component" error! Because I never told the test to mount the popup component!

Neat! (and frustrating)

Leaving this question otherwise as-is for historical reasons, especially since I've found an appreciation for those people who  post solutions to their obscure problems.

Comment: I think you should throw a `nuxt` tag on your post, might be easier for people to discover

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer I had the same problem! 